# XSLT 1.0 - Multiple Child Nodes Formatted Output

Tags: xslt, nodes

I can do this with For-Each but having some problems with Apply_Templates.

The XML Data contains varying child nodes but I want to display all child nodes with their parents information.

```
<orders>
<order>
    <customer>1</customer>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Widget A</name>
            <price>10</price>
            <code>1A</code>
        </item>
    </items>
</order>
<order>
    <customer>2</customer>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Widget A</name>
            <price>10</price>
            <code>1A</code>
        </item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Widget B</name>
            <price>20</price>
            <code>2B</code>
        </item>
    </items>
</order>
<order>
    <customer>3</customer>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Widget A</name>
            <price>10</price>
            <code>1A</code>
        </item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Widget B</name>
            <price>10</price>
            <code>1A</code>
        </item>
    </items>
    <items>
        <item>
            <name>Widget C</name>
            <price>30</price>
            <code>3C</code>
        </item>
    </items>
</order>
```

As you can see, there are multiple item per customer per order.  I want the output to look like this:

```
Customer, Name, Price, Code
1, Widget A, 10, 1A
2, Widget A, 10, 1A
2, Widget B, 20, 2B
3, Widget A, 10, 1A
3, Widget B, 20, 2B
3, Widget C, 30, 3C
```

When I to apply-templates, I can only get the first item to display but not the others.  If you think I should post my XSL, let me know but I think it should be simple just stuck.  I want to get away from using for-each.

Comment: Yes, please post your XSLT.

Comment: "I want to get away from using for-each.*" Why? You have a regular, almost flat structure, and there would be practically nothing for individual templates to do. Using `xsl:for-each` would be the winning approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Customer, Name, Price ,Code&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//item"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../customer"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

- First template match the root element and print header in the output document.
- The 2nd template match `item` elements and output corresponding comma-separated values. This way you can have rows from each `item` in the output document without using `for-each` construct.

Comment: This will definitely do, +1. `concat()` function would make it look simple.

Comment: This is practically the same thing as using `xsl:for-each`. A template-based approach would have a separate template for dealing with the order items. -- In addition, you should avoid the processor-intensive `//` and select the item nodes by using the known, explicit path.

Comment: I was advised to stay away from for-each as much as possible and have been using for-each exclusively.  I'm just trying to solve this problem using apply-templates.   I don't fully yet understand why for-each is not recommended versus apply-templates.   I will look at this solution and try it with some similar examples.  Thanks!

Comment: So this works like I wanted for apply-templates in other samples that I have.  Much appreciated!  At least I have some tools to solve using both methods; for-each and apply-templates.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a truly template-based approach would look like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/orders">
    <xsl:text>Customer, Name, Price, Code&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="order/items/item"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="../../customer"/>
    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item/*">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, as I mentioned in the comment to your question, this serves no discernible purpose, other than breaking the code into discontinuous chunks that are hard to follow.